# Link Harvesting in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am both amazed and really frustrated with Scrapy. It seems like there is too much power under the hood, making it a really steep learning curve. Apparently, Scrapy can do everything that I used to program myself, but the problem is figuring out how to make it do what I want.

For now, I am writing a simple link harvester. I want to export two files: one with internal links and link text, and another with external link and link text.

I have been trying to us the -o file.csv command, but it lumps each page url into a single cell as a list, and it includes duplicates.

The alternative that I have would be to just write my own code in 'parse' and manually create a list of links and check to see if they exist in the list before adding them, and then manually parse the url to see if the domain in internal or external.

It seems like Scrapy should do this with a few commands. Is there a built-in method for this?

Here's the code that I am working with. I commented out the title part bc I think I need to make another item object for those. I've abandoned that part for now.

```
    def parse_items(self, response):
    item = WebconnectItem()
    sel = Selector(response)
    items = []
#    item["title"] = sel.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
#    item["current_url"] = response.url
    item["link_url"] = sel.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
    item["link_text"] = sel.xpath('//a/text()').extract()
    items.append(item)
    return items
```

Comment: can you share you code? It will help guide you through a solution

Comment: i'd suggest using requests, and beautifulsoup 4. I've tried Scrapy and I felt the same, if you'd want I can come up with a simple guide on it

Comment: I added the code. I think you might be right about requests and BS4. I already have my crawler working, but was attracted by all that Scrapy can do. With requests and BS4, I know everything that happens. With Scrapy, I feel like you throw code into the void and god knows what will come out.

Comment: I think Scrapy does have a learning curve since it's based on the idea of a loop. I've tried, didn't really like it.

Comment: @taesu `lxml` >> `BS4`. Much faster, even includes beautiful soup internally. Also, the docs to fix your duplication problem are [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html)

Comment: @SlaterTyranus I never argued which one is faster...?

Comment: @taesu sorry, that was just one example of why I think `lxml` is a better choice than BS4. That and the fact that it is a strict superset of functionality.

Comment: I use lxml with BS4. It resolved some funky results I was getting.

Comment: I wrote an example code below, take a look

Comment: @taesu so reading that link, I have to create a pipeline to handle duplicates, which appears to be the same code I would use with requests. This really makes me wonder what the value is with Scrapy. Maybe it is just for large projects.

Comment: @JoshuaMeyer The value in scrapy is that you will scrape ~8x faster, get automatic error handling, and stay robust to internet failure.

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy has [extensive documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/) and [the tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) is a good introduction.

It's built on top of Twisted so you have to think in terms of asynchronous requests and responses, which is quite different from what you usually do with python-requests and BS4. python-requests blocks your thread when issuing HTTP requests. Scrapy does not, it lets you process responses while other requests may be over the wire.

You can use BS4 in scrapy callbacks (e.g. in your `parse_items` method).

You're right that Scrapy will output 1 item per line in its output. It will not do any deduplication of URLs because items are just items for Scrapy. They happen to contain URLs in your case.
Scrapy does no deduplication of items based on what they contain. You'd have to instruct it to do so (with an [item pipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) for example)

As for URLs represented as lists in your `link_url` and `link_text` fields, it's because `sel.xpath('//a/@href').extract()` [returns lists](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.SelectorList.extract)

Scrapy 1.0 (soon to be released) adds an [`.extract_first()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/selectors.html) method that would help in your case.

Comment: The item pipeline is the key that is missing in the tutorials I've done. The way you explain it is clearer. So basically pipelines is the 'code' portion of scrapy. I was trying to dump everything in the crawler not realizing it should go in the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll see to update the docs and tutorial about pipelines. Scrapy callbacks are meant to extract items from pages. Pipelines are one way to work with items while they're being processed, one at a time (so you could keep a `set()` of `(url, text)` tuples and ignore an item if its values are already in the set. Exporting 2 files could be [a bit trickier](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/exporters.html), you may be better off splitting the output after the fact (you could have an internal/external field in your item definition to help group the links.

Comment: This is getting clearer as you explain it. This is the type of info I have been trying to find. I've read the docs a few times, but these details that hold it all together are missing. The int/ext field is a good idea. I would also like to run keyword analysis on each internal page, weighting title, h1, etc. I imagine this would be a pipeline code, too. Then, I would do an 'if internal' code that executes the keyword analysis. This is making more sense. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

So, your thoughts about `scrapy` are largely accurate. Very powerful, steep learning curve, but has a lot of promise if you can get past that part. There are even a few value-added services on top like ScrapingHub that can take care of rotating IP addresses, keeping jobs running, etc...

The difference is that scrapy works using item pipelines rather than the traditional model. They have great code to resolve exactly the issue that you're having. Any processing of results should happen in these item pipelines rather than in the scraper itself. The docs are [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html), and this is an example pipeline for removing duplicates and writing to json:

```
class DuplicatesPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen = set()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['id'] in self.ids_seen:
            raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
        else:
            self.ids_seen.add(item['id'])
            return item

class JsonWriterPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.file = open('items.jl', 'wb')

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        line = json.dumps(dict(item)) + "\n"
        self.file.write(line)
        return item
```

Comment: That makes sense. Though this opens it's own can of worms. Are these items stored in memory while they are in the pipeline, or stored in a file that needs to be read first? Does it export one item at a time, or the whole list?

Comment: @JoshuaMeyer It's really made to be one item at a time, and not everything is held in memory at once. Since everything happens asynchronously the item pipeline methods are used as callbacks. They enter the pipeline through the scraper, and are then written out to disk (as in the jsonwriter example) Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

**Implementation using requests & bs4**
note it's not the optimal solution, but it shows how it can be done using requests and bs4.
the goto setup for me.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = "http://www.cnn.com/"

# get request
r = requests.get(URL) 
# turn into bs instance
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text) 
# get all links
links = soup.findAll('a')

internal_unique = []
external_unique = []
internal_links = []
external_links = []

for link in links:
    if 'ccn.com' in link['href'] or link['href'].startswith('/'):
        if link['href'] not in internal_unique:
            internal_links.append({'link':link['href'],'text':link.get_text()})
            internal_unique.append(link['href'])
    else:
        if link['href'] not in external_unique:
            external_links.append({'link':link['href'],'text':link.get_text()})
            external_unique.append(link['href'])
print internal_links
print external_links
```

Comment: It is so freaking simple in requests! I use urlparse on all the links, then run an if statement on the 'netloc'.

Comment: requests >> any other http library